# Where is record created with rails g scaffold CRUD?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crud

I created a record using `rails g scaffold User name:string` and then created a new instance of User using the interface on the users view. Now I cannot find where the record has been saved. I checked my seeds.rb file? not there... Where does crud save records to? Thanks

Comment: It saves to the working DB, probably a sqlite file.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: thanks for the db info

Seeds.rb is for seeding the database it is not the database itself.  If you just ran rails new  and then created a scaffold your default database is where the data will be saved.  Assuming you ran the migrations.

If you want to interactively check if the data is there run `rails console`, and from the interactive console you can query User (e.g. `User.first`) to find the data you've saved.

Comment: I was wondering where on my file system? Somewhere in mysql folders?

Comment: Wherever you set up MySQL in the first place. You presumably have your MySQL DB up and running first. Migrations create your new DB against your local MySQL server.